# upload and install to aws server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, upload, web-deployment

I have a test server that checks out my source from github and deploys it locally to my test server.

Now I have it running and tested. I want to upload that working directory to AWS server's, how do I do this?
I have access to AWS via putty.

Then when I have it all on the aws server, can I install it as I would on any other ubuntu server?

Comment: use ``scp`` or do another git checkout on the remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option, which worked best for me.

Is create an AWS instance, log into it.
Set that up as you would any other server.
then you can save the image and use as a base in future.

I used Ubuntu, but there are numerous AWS instances available.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this:

- Make a tar ball, scp to your server, untar and install
- Use Ansible to checkout code on your server
- Best option: Use [AWS Code Deploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/) See this [Using AWS CodeDeploy to Deploy an Application from GitHub](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ-tutorial.html)